# How to add pagination on BBPRESS forums page?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, bbpress

I want to add pagination on forums pages after 10 forums list: http://nimb.ws/MEUyK2

Answer (score 0):

Add this PHP function to your child themes `functions.php` file or in a plugin like functionality to increase the total amount of forums in the page. It may also be better to just show the Topics by Freshness in the forum root instead by setting it in Settings > Forums.

```
function rkk_increase_forum_per_page( $args ) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] = get_option( '_bbp_forums_per_page', 150 );
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'bbp_before_has_forums_parse_args', 'rkk_increase_forum_per_page' );
```

[Reference](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/pagination-for-forums-listing/)

Comment: I have already tried this, this filter only change posts per page not add pagination